# User in Form-Class

Tags: python, django

I have a form like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
[...]
```

which is rendered in my view:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = MyForm(request.GET)
```

Now, i want to add a form field which contains a set of values in a select-field, and the queryset must be filtered by the currently logged in user. So I changed the method signature so that it contains the request-object:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.myfield  = forms.ChoiceField([('%s' % d.id, '%s' % d.name) for d in MyModel.objects.filter(owners = user)])
```

but all I get after rendering the form is an object-reference as string instead of the select-widget. I seems that a form field, once declared, can not be modified.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last line of code with this:

```
self.fields['myfield'].choices = [('%s' % d.id, '%s' % d.name) for d in MyModel.objects.filter(owners = user)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here's what you're after:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['myfield']  = forms.ModelChoiceField(MyModel.objects.filter(owners=user))
```

That's assuming that the `__unicode__` method of your `MyModel` returns  `self.name`.
If this *isn't* the case, then you can subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override the `label_from_instance` method.